# How to set chart element on chart in excel using apple script

Tags: excel, applescript

This script is through error "Microsoft Excel got an error: worksheet "sheet1" of active workbook doesn’t understand the set chart element message."

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object 1
           tell ochart1
               set chart element chart element 1
               --- create the chart title on chart with value 1
           end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

[image].

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This also works. Why do you want to create a chart title using set chart element command?

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object 1
        tell ochart1
            set chart title text of it's chart title to "My Title"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi, your script is run successfully and create a chart title but i want to create a chart title using set chart element command. set chart element command is present in apple dictionary in office 2011.This command have a multiple value.

Comment: set chart title command is work in VBA code (see a picture )and is work on window for office 2007 and 2010 using OLE. so i want to create a chat title using set chart element command.

Comment: Hi, In this script how to apply above chart title and overlay chart title on chart.and how to apply a legend position is right , left,top,bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a chart title this worked for me:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object 1
        tell ochart1
            set has title to true                       
            set caption of its chart title to "your title here"         
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi, your script is run successfully and create a chart title but i want to create a chart title using set chart element command.

Comment: I can't see any set chart element command in the Excel's applescript dictionary, instead I see a get chart element command. Where did you find set chart element?

Comment: It works on my machine running 10.6.8. See the newly posted apple script command .

Comment: Probably is the version of Microsoft Excel that make the difference

Comment: Hi, My office version for excel is 2011.

Comment: Anyway, the chart section in dictionary lists all the possible values for chart elements (shapes, arcs, etc.), title is not included, so I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: Ok. office 2008 is install on another mac machine.In apple script dictionary only see get chart element command.

Comment: I am manually apply a chart element while macro is running mode(see a VBA code image). chart element value "msoElementChartTitleAboveChart" is present.